# When would you not use Generic Collections?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

The advantage of using generics is that it increases the type safety - you can only put in the correct type of thing, and you get out the correct type without requiring a cast. The only reason I can think of for not using generic collections is that you need to store some arbitrary data. Am I missing something? What other reasons are there to not use generics when dealing with collections?

Comment: I switched 'container' to 'collection' since that's how they're referred to in C#.

Comment: Lots of good answers here, thanks everyone

Answer (score 17):

If you need to store arbitrary data, use `List<object>` (or whatever). Then it's absolutely clear that it's *deliberately* arbitrary.

Other than that, I wouldn't use the non-generic collections for anything. I *have* used `IEnumerable` and `IList` when I've been converting an `object` reference and didn't know the type to cast it to at compile-time - so non-generic *interfaces* are useful sometimes... but not the non-generic classes themselves.

Answer (score 7):

The obvious other reason is working with code (possibly legacy) that does not use generic collections.

You can see this happening in .NET itself. `System.Windows.Form.Control.Controls` is not generic, nor is `System.Web.UI.Control.Controls`.

Answer (score 3):

Generics are almost always the right thing to use. Note that languages like Haskell and ML essentially *only* allow that model: there is no default "object" or "void*" in those languages at all.

The only reasons I might not use generics are:

1. When the appropriate type is simply not known at compile time. Things like deserializing objects, or instantiating objects through reflection.
2. When the users that will be using my code aren't familiar with them (yet). Not all engineers are comfortable using them, especially in some more advanced patterns like the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage is the is no boxing or unboxing penalty with generic collections of value types. This can be seen if you examine the il using ildasm.exe. The generic containers give better performance for value types and a smaller performance improvement for reference types.

Answer (score 2):

[Type variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx) with generics can trip you up, but mostly you *should* use generic collections.  There isn't a really a good reason to avoid them, and all the reason in the world to avoid un-typed collections like ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one answer: [The change from `Hashtable` to `Dictionary`](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/04/26/120438.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

One thing I think you need to consider is that a generic collection is not always a drop in replacement for a non-generic collection.  For example, Dictionary<object,object> can **not** simply be plugged in for an instance of Hashtable.  They have very different behavior in a number of scenarios that can and will break programs.  Switching between these two collections forces a good programmer to examine the use cases to ensure the differences do not bite them.

Comment: Can you give an example? I cant think of any reason why hashtable and dictionary<object,object> arent interchangable. (minus a few syntax changes obviously)

Comment: Actually the classic example is the behaviour when the item is not found. HashTable returns null while dictionary throws an exception

Comment: hrm. That is certainly true, but id still treat that as a syntax-ish issue. a simple extension method to return null if the key is not contained would get you back to hash functionality

Answer (score 0):

The non-generic `Collection` in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace has some annoying quirks and goofiness, and is in a lot of ways pretty horrible, but it also has a unique feature: it is the only collection which exhibits sensible semantics if it's modified during an enumeration; code which does something like delete all members of a Collection which meet a certain predicate may need to be significantly rewritten if some other collection type is used.