# how to sort List<T> in c# / .net

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a class `PropertyDetails`:

```
public class PropertyDetails
{

     public int Sequence { get; set; }

     public int Length { get; set; }

     public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating a list of `PropertyDetails` as

```
List<PropertyDetails> propertyDetailsList=new List<PropertyDetails>();
```

I want to sort this list by `PropertyDetails.Sequence`.

Linq solutions are welcome.

Comment: List<PropertyDetails> propertyDetailsList=new List<PropertyDetails>();

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to sort arrays without allocating any memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730010/is-there-a-way-to-sort-arrays-without-allocating-any-memory)

Answer (score 39):

If you want to sort the existing list in-place then you can use the [`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method:

```
List<PropertyDetails> propertyDetailsList = ...
propertyDetailsList.Sort((x, y) => x.Sequence.CompareTo(y.Sequence));
```

If you want to create a new, sorted copy of the list then you can use LINQ's [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method:

```
List<PropertyDetails> propertyDetailsList = ...
var sorted = propertyDetailsList.OrderBy(x => x.Sequence).ToList();
```

(And if you don't need the results as a concrete `List<T>` then you can omit the final `ToList` call.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever use non-generic collections in C# when you can use generics instead. There are a lot of reasons to use **generic collections only** (except for very special cases).

See this question for more info:
[When would you not use Generic Collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700669/why-not-use-generic-collections)

So you can use `List<PropertyDetails>` (which I believe exposes a `Sort()` method) or `SortedList<,>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using linq you can crate a new sorted list:

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.Sequence).ToList();
```

If you want to sort your current list, you can use a comparer:

```
list.Sort((details1, details2) => details1.Sequence.CompareTo(details2.Sequence);
```

Comment: This is not "in place", and is less efficient as it must create an entirely new collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sortedList = propertyDetailsList.OrderBy(pd => pd.Sequence);
```

Comment: Is actually not sorting the list, but creating a new IEnumerable which contains the sorted items... I still think that this is the requested solution.

Comment: It is not a "sortedList". It is a "IOrderableEnumerable<T>". It needs a .ToList() to make an actual "sortedList".

Comment: hence the use of "var", sortedList is just the variable name

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that calling something `sortedList` and then using `var` to hide the fact that it's not, in fact, a sorted list is just really bad practice.