# Is there a way to sort arrays without allocating any memory?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to sort a rather big collection (high hundreds/low thousands of items) very frequently, that is every frame at 60 fps (I'm using Unity).
Computing the key for each item is sort of slow so it needs to be cached.

I've tried various approaches:

- List.Sort() with IComparer, computing the key every time: super slow
- SortedList: MUCH faster, but generates GC allocs (30KB/frame): why? is they key boxed (I'm using a long)? is the key/value pair allocated? If I wrap the long in a class, the GC is halved, so my guess is "both": 1 alloc for the pair, one alloc to box the key if it's a value type...
- Array.Sort(keyArray, valueArray): horrendous! slow & generates 256KB of GC/frame!

It's a shame because SortedList seemed perfect for the job, is there any GC-free alternative that I'm missing?

Comment: Is it critical for it to be on each frame? maybe you could compute it across several frames using [coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html)

Comment: *any* memory, no. You need at least a swap variable to perform any kind of sort. THe memory used depends on the algorithm, an Insertion or Selection sort takes almost no memory, a Quick Sort is faster and also uses very little memory. You could implement one yourself and see how it does against whatever .NET is using!

Comment: [This](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com) can get you started.

Comment: Try using `SortedDictionary`, the memory footprint will be smaller. And it could be faster in your case, too.

Comment: Have you contemplated using a [SortedSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) to manage your items instead of a `List<T>`? This would keep the items in sort order, so no sort would be needed.

Comment: In which unity method are you sorting it?

Comment: - Yes it has to be on each frame, and it has to be immediate (cannot be threaded).

Comment: @wdosanjos: ah, thank you! I was looking for that (SortedList but without the key/value pair, just the value)... unfortunately the reason I didn't find is it's not available in Unity, which uses .NET 3.5, and SortedSet was introduced in 4.0.
Also, from looking at the source from Mono, it allocates a Node on each Add so it's gonna be the same issue.
Also I can see now why it's much faster, it's using an RBTree, whereas List/Array.Sort seems to be a qsort.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: well yeah I need to swap, but I don't see why the swap var should be allocated, it could be on the stack.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: yes I think I may have to implement my own sorting...

Comment: @MVCDS: in OnPreCull (Camera callback). Why?

Comment: I tried to find a image or link to support my point, but I'm entering work right now, so I'll pass it later (if you want).
I know some methods are called for frames and others don't depend on them, so I was guessing if you could optimize your process by doing it on other method.

`If you want to change camera's viewing parameters (e.g. fieldOfView or just transform), this is the place to do it. Visibility of scene objects will be determined based on camera's parameters after OnPreCull.`

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPreCull.html

Comment: @PatriceGahide thanks, I've just tried SortedDictionary... unfortunately the memory footprint is similar (apparently it also uses an RBTree).

Comment: Not to be *too* pedantic, but a stack variable is still "allocated" , just differently. That being said, I would implement your own sort if the .NET ones aren't good enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

If computing keys is so slow, you can add `key` property to your item class, calculate it before sorting, and then use your first method with `IComparer` simply comparing keys.

Comment: Yes I've tried this approach, but the thing is List.Sort is quite slow in itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: You can use `List.Sort` with a `static Func<>` to sort
without per-frame allocation. It will allocate a small amount on first
use, but doesn't allocate more for each subsequent sort.

Avoid using IComparer because it seems to cause per-frame allocations.

For truly zero allocations, you'll need to implement your own sort
algorithm. However, you'll need to ensure your sort is faster than the built-in without additional memory usage. Note that [List.Sort's Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0) describes the three possible sort algorithms it uses. I may be missing something by failing to exercise all the implementation details.

Here's some code marked up for [Unity's Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html) and the readings I got from the profiler. It uses @AntonSavin's suggestion to compute the key before sorting, demonstrates Insertion sort with 0 allocations, and compares several ways of invoking `List.Sort()`:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Profiling;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

static class SortTest {

[UnityEditor.MenuItem("Tools/Sort numbers")]
static void Menu_SortNumbers()
{
    var data = new List<Data>(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        data.Add(new Data{ Value = Random.Range(0, 10000) });
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; ++i)
    {
        data[i].ComputeExpensiveKey();
    }

    var to_sort = Enumerable.Range(0, 8)
        .Select(x => data.ToList())
        .ToList();

    // Focus is GC so we re-run the sort several times to validate
    // additional sorts don't have additional cost.
    const int num_iterations = 100;

    // GC Alloc: 0 B
    Profiler.BeginSample("Sort 1,000 items 1 time - Insertion"); {
        InsertionSort(to_sort[0], compare_bool);
    }
    Profiler.EndSample();

    // GC Alloc: 0 B
    // Time ms: 16.47
    Profiler.BeginSample("Sort 1,000 items 100 times - Insertion"); {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i) {
            InsertionSort(to_sort[1], compare_bool);
        }
    }
    Profiler.EndSample();

    // GC Alloc: 48 B
    // Alloc is static -- first use is automatically cached.
    Profiler.BeginSample("Sort 1,000 items 1 time - List.Sort Comparison");
    {
        to_sort[2].Sort(compare_int);
    }
    Profiler.EndSample();

    // GC Alloc: 0 B (because of previous sample)
    // Time ms: 8.51
    Profiler.BeginSample("Sort 1,000 items 100 times - List.Sort Comparison"); {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i) {
            to_sort[3].Sort(compare_int);
        }
    }
    Profiler.EndSample();

    // GC Alloc: 112 B
    Profiler.BeginSample("Sort 1,000 items 1 time - List.Sort lambda"); {
            to_sort[4].Sort((a,b) => {
                if (a.PrecomputedKey < b.PrecomputedKey)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a.PrecomputedKey > b.PrecomputedKey)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
    }
    Profiler.EndSample();

    // GC Alloc: 112 B
    // Time ms: 8.75
    // Seems like this does a callsite caching (for some reason more than
    // Comparison). Each location that invokes Sort incurs this alloc.
    Profiler.BeginSample("Sort 1,000 items 100 times - List.Sort lambda"); {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i) {
            to_sort[5].Sort((a,b) => {
                if (a.PrecomputedKey < b.PrecomputedKey)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a.PrecomputedKey > b.PrecomputedKey)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
        }
    }
    Profiler.EndSample();

    // GC Alloc: 112 B
    Profiler.BeginSample("Sort 1,000 items 1 time - List.Sort IComparer"); {
            to_sort[6].Sort(compare_icomparer);
    }
    Profiler.EndSample();

    // GC Alloc: 10.9 KB (num_iterations * 112 B)
    // Time ms: 8.48
    Profiler.BeginSample("Sort 1,000 items 100 times - List.Sort IComparer"); {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_iterations; ++i) {
            to_sort[7].Sort(compare_icomparer);
        }
    }
    Profiler.EndSample();

    Profiler.enabled = false;


    // Make sure they sorted the same.
    for (int i = 0; i < to_sort[0].Count; ++i)
    {
        foreach (var list in to_sort)
        {
            UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.AreEqual(to_sort[0][i].Value, list[i].Value);
        }
    }
    Debug.Log("Done SortNumbers");
}

class Data
{
    public int PrecomputedKey;
    public int Value;
    public void ComputeExpensiveKey()
    {
        // something expensive here
        PrecomputedKey = Value;
    }
}

// Create outside of your loop to reduce allocations.
static Func<Data,Data,bool> compare_bool = (a,b) => a.PrecomputedKey > b.PrecomputedKey;
static Comparison<Data> compare_int = (a,b) => {
    if (a.PrecomputedKey < b.PrecomputedKey)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.PrecomputedKey > b.PrecomputedKey)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
};
static IComparer<Data> compare_icomparer = Comparer<Data>.Create((a,b) => {
    if (a.PrecomputedKey < b.PrecomputedKey)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.PrecomputedKey > b.PrecomputedKey)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});

static void InsertionSort<T>(List<T> items, Func<T,T,bool> compare)
{
    var len = items.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        var current = items[i];
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0 && !compare(current, items[j]); --j)
        {
            items[j+1] = items[j];
            items[j] = current;
        }
    }
}

}
```