# Is there a way to perform a List<int>.Sort() without any memory allocations?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory, garbage-collection

I am using C# in Unity and so would like to avoid any memory allocations when sorting a list.  When I call `List<int>.Sort()` under the hood it seems to call `Array.Sort()` and `ArraySortHelper.Sort()` which allocates the memory according to the Unity profiler. To avoid this I have resorted to writing my own allocation-free generic quicksort algorithm, but I'm so surprised that this is necessary for something so basic as sorting a List of ints, that I thought I would ask if anybody can point me to some simple memory allocation free method of sorting a list in the standard library.

EDIT

I am aware of the following question: [Is there a way to sort arrays without allocating any memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730010/is-there-a-way-to-sort-arrays-without-allocating-any-memory). My requirements are quite different.  I do not have any issues with Keys being slow to compute (it is specifically a `List` of type `int`) and I cannot use the `SortedSet` suggested in the comments of that question as elements may have duplicates. I am not concerned about the performance of the algorithm in particular, I would just like to find some standard library implementation that is readily available that can sort a List of ints without any resulting memory allocations. It does not have to be a method on the class itself, I have coded my own static generic quicksort which works fine, but I hope to find something like it that has already been implemented somewhere in standard libraries because it feels like such a basic thing that I should not have to maintain my own function to complete that task.

Many thanks!

Comment: Unity is based on Mono which is open sourced so you can look at the code https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#L976

Comment: @Jonathan thank you, but unfortunately not - I found that question too, but nowhere in it do people talk about the memory allocation in List<T>.Sort() itself, and there are no alternatives proposed which avoid List<T>.Sort() memory allocations.

Comment: @SirRufo Thank you very much for that pointer, I did not know I look through the source. On inspection it appears every Sort available on the List class does go through an Array sort which allocates memory, so maybe it is necessary to implement my own unless there is some static functions available outside of the class which can do it.

Comment: @PatrickBeynio Thank you! Yes it does, passing in a function directly as answered in that question seems to prevent the memory allocation: ```List<int>.Sort((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));```